# unlink mat-slider thumb Label value from slider's bar progression

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material2

I would like to choose a value for the mat-slider thumb Label and another value for the horizontal bar progression

[image]

Here what I expect ( I have used devtools to get the result

[image]

I have noticed that I should change css values of `mat-slider-track-background` ==> grey line and `mat-slider-track-fill` ==> yellow line

I don't know how to do it programmatically because the value of the yellow bar is send dynamically from the parent component and the bar html component is a child of mat-slider so I can't set class from template file

```
<mat-slider
    class="example-margin"
    [disabled]="false"
    [invert]="invert"
    [max]="max"
    [min]="min"
    [step]="step"
    [thumbLabel]="true"
    [tickInterval]="tickInterval"
    [(ngModel)]='value'
    [vertical]="vertical">
</mat-slider>
```

In my ts file I have the second value and slider params :

```
export class SliderConfigurableExample {
  value2= 60; <== I would like this to be the bar value
}
```

Here's a [reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slider-dynamic-valuess?file=src/app/slider-configurable-example.ts)

Comment: The design of the component is based on a single value that is represented by both the thumb and the track fill. The display of those two elements is not configurable except possibly by hacking - but even then I don't think it's possible because the position is bound to the single value.

Comment: It's possible by changing `mat-slider-track-background` and `mat-slider-track-fill` css  classes ( possible with devtools ) so I think it's possible to do change it on code

Comment: You can change it in dev tools, but I don't think it will stay changed when the value changes. The translate styling is bound inside MatSlider. Every time the slider value is changed, the style tag on those elements is updated. Have you made it work from inside a component? Please share your code.

Comment: I have Not yet make it work , In my example I use the matSlider as a chart so I blocked the cursor events ( a readonly mode )that means that I will not have the problem you pointed